# How to evaluate this integral using Parseval’s formula?

Tags: fourier-transform

> Parseval’s formula state that
>
> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathopen|f(x)\mathclose|^2 dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathopen|F(k)\mathclose|^2 dk$$

How to use Parseval’s formula to evaluate the following integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+k^2)^2}dk$$.

Comment: @CaveJohnson the Fourier of $1/(1+x^2)$ is $\pi$.

Comment: @CaveJohnson yes my bad. The Fourier of $1/(1+x^2)$ is $\pi(e^{-k}H(k)-e^{k} H(k)+e^{k})$.

Comment: I can evaluate the integral in question directly by just using $k=\tan(x)$.

Comment: Of course, but you asked to solve it using Parseval's formula. The Fourier transform you obtained can be simplified into $\pi e^{-|k|}$, right? Can you take it from here?

Comment: @CaveJohnson Something like this
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+k^2)^2} dk=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2|x|}dx=1$$
Thus
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+k^2)^2} dk=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
Is this the correct way? I messed up with the Fourier transform definition. For the Parseval's formula I used the one with $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Comment: It looks good. As for the Parseval's formula, if your definition of Fourier transform contains a $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$, then Parseval's formula does not contain $1/(2\pi)$; if your definition of Fourier transform does not contain $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$, then you need to add a $1/(2\pi)$ in Parseval's formula.